# Is there any practical reason why std::get_if (std::variant) takes a variant argument by pointer instead of by value/&/const&?

Tags: c++, c++17, pass-by-reference, std-variant, pass-by-pointer

I've never used [`std::get_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if), and since its name is different from [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get), I don't see a reason why its argument should be a pointer¹ (whereas `std::get` has a by-reference parameter).

---

¹If it was named `std::get` too, then overload resolution would be a reason enough.

---

Yes, my *question* could be duped to the *question* [Is it absolutely necessary for std::any_cast() and std::get_if(std::variant) to take pointer as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617907/is-it-absolutely-necessary-for-stdany-cast-and-stdget-ifstdvariant-to), but the point is that there's no *answer* there that addresses `std::get_if` vs `std::get`, just one comment; the only answer concentrates on `std::any_cast`.

Comment: I seem to recall Jason Turner talking about why that is in one of the C++ Weekly videos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it absolutely necessary for std::any\_cast() and std::get\_if(std::variant) to take pointer as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617907/is-it-absolutely-necessary-for-stdany-cast-and-stdget-ifstdvariant-to)

Comment: @xskxzr, no, for the reason I've added in the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because [`get_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) is `noexcept`, so an exception will never be thrown. In order to achieve this, it must return a `pointer` so that `nullptr` can be returned when the access fails.

Because it returned the pointer, it must take the pointer of the `variant`. If it takes the reference of `variant`, then it must be able to accept the type of `variant&`, `const variant&`, `variant&&` and `const variant&&`, but it does not make sense for the pointer to remain ref-qualified.

Considering that `get_if` accepts `variant&&`, what you do is return the address of an xvalue, which is terrible. Even if `get_if` only allows `variant&` and `const variant&`, the latter can still accept a `variant&&` and return a dangling.

Comment: I truly don't understand the explanation in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Enlico. Assuming `get_if` accepts references, what type should it return when it accepts `variant&&`?

Comment: `variant&&` would bind only to rvalues, right? Then wouldn't returning a `nullptr` be the right choice?

Comment: @Enlico. That can be a choice, but it also means that `get_if(std::move(v))` will return a `nullptr` even if there is no problem returning its address.

Comment: It's just like `unique_ptr.get()` I don't see the reason it's any more invalid for `variant`.

Comment: The `variant &&` issue can be easily resolved with an `= delete` overload, if necessary.

Comment: This seems to be describing why `get_if` *returns* a pointer, not why it *takes* a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell, it is based off dynamic cast logic.  The dynamic cast that can fail takes a pointer and returns a pointer.

Similarly, get that can fail takes a pointer and returns one.

But really it looks like a tiny bikeshed decision of not much importance.

Answer (score 2):

This design allows you to apply "chained" invocations like this:

```
struct A : public std::variant<int, float>{};

int main()
{
    std::variant<A, char> f;
    A a;
    static_cast<std::variant<int, float>&>(a) = 10;
    f = a;
    cout << *std::get_if<int>(std::get_if<A>(&f));
    return 0;
}
```